# Is there a way to hide a code using Swift Package Manager?

Tags: swift, xcode

I would like to create a lib, but I don't want my code to be open. I took a look at a few package manager tutorials and looks like there is no way to write a lib using this approach and hide the code, for example, there is some code that I don't have the rights to share with everyone.

So, the question is there a way to create a lib with help of Swift Package Manager https://swift.org/package-manager/ , but with a closed code source?

Answer (score 3):

The page you referenced is pretty clear:

> A package consists of Swift source files and a manifest file

This is backed up by the very first sentence in the Swift Package Manager documentation in the projects GitHub repository:

https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/tree/main/Documentation

> The Swift Package Manager is a tool for managing distribution of
> source code, aimed at making it easy to share your code and reuse
> others’ code.

Both mention the Package Manager as a tool for distributing **Source Code**